# Why isn't the first docker argument value working in the COPY command

Tags: docker

This is the simplest, reproducible example.  At first, I thought it was a problem with my multi-stage dockerfile but I can't echo the value of an ARG using the simplest Dockerfile that I can create. To reproduce create a sub-directory named test-data and put a zip file with anything that has the name 25_31-linux64-redhat8-testbundle.zip

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8-micro
ARG swversion=25
ARG build=31
RUN set -e; \
    echo "swversion $swversion, Build $build"
    
COPY test-data/$swversion_$build-linux64-redhat8-testbundle.zip \
     ./
RUN yum -y install unzip; \
    unzip $swversion_$build-linux64-redhat8-testbundle.zip
```

Output still doesn't echo the correct variable value for swversion.  It does appear that the default value of build is filled in.  Used command "docker build -f Dockerfileargs ."

```
Step 1/6 : FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8-micro
 ---> 62c33d061724
Step 2/6 : ARG swversion=25
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d15b4200fccc
Step 3/6 : ARG build=31
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 497601dff448
Step 4/6 : RUN set -e;  echo "swversion $swversion, Build $build"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fc4df82f949a
Step 5/6 : COPY test-data/$swversion_$build-linux64-redhat8-testbundle.zip      ./
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat test-data/31-linux64-redhat8-testbundle.zip: file does not exist
```

Why is the value for the ARG swversion missing when the COPY command executes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names tend to be "greedy" as in they'll use as many characters as they can to make the name. Consider for example<sup>(1)</sup>:

```bash
pax> export xxx=X
pax> export yyy=Y
pax> echo a: $xxx$yyy
a: XY
pax> echo b: $xxx_$yyy
b: Y
pax> echo c: ${xxx}_${yyy}
c: X_Y
```

The reason the `7` is missing in that `b` command above is because it's *not* evaluating the `xxx` variable then echoing a literal underscore. It is instead evaluating the `xxx_` variable (not set to anything in this case, so evaluates to an empty string). In other words, it's effectively evaluating `${xxx_}${yyy}`.

You would be better off enclosing all your variable names in braces to properly delineate them, such as with the `c` command above, which gives you the expected output.

In your (Docker) case, that would be:

```
COPY test-data/${swversion}_${build}-linux64-redhat8-testbundle.zip ./
```

---

As an aside, here's a very similar line from one of our own Docker files, showing how we do it:

```
COPY ${APP_NAME}/poetry.lock ${APP_NAME}/pyproject.toml ./
```

It's not actually *needed* in that case since `/` is not a valid character for environment variable names so it would not be absorbed into that name. However, we *always* use braces for consistency, and it's safer in case someone less knowledgeable modifies it later without realising.

This is also why your `build` variable is being substituted correctly, since the `-` character following it is *also* not a valid character for environment variable names.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Yes, I realise this is `bash` rather than Docker but they act very similar in terms of evaluating variables, and I'm not going to go to the trouble of creating a whole Docker image just to illustrate the concept :-)

Comment: Thank you.  That did solve my particular problem. I was able to discover that via some experimentation just before you posted your answer but that is a good explanation of why the problem was occurring.